# Clicking on Placemark leads to wrong location

Tags: google-maps, kml

The following simple example illustrates a problem I am having with ALL my KML files:

[Link to Simple KML Example](https://maps.google.ca/?q=https://sites.google.com/site/mbkmltest/my-kml-test/Test2.kml)

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
<Document>
  <name>KML Example file</name>
  <description>Simple markers</description>

  <Placemark>
    <name>Marker 1</name>
    <description>Some stuff to put in the first info window</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-122.1,37.4,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>

</Document>
</kml>
```

It loads into Google Maps just fine.  The one Placemarker Icon appears in the right location, but when I click on marker 1 in the left panel, Google Maps moves to the Atlantic Ocean just south of Ghana.

I have tried various simple and complex KML files and they all to this.  If I use the My Places upload function on the same files this particular behaviour does not happen.

I am using Chrome 21 and Windows 7.

Thanks anyone!

Comment: When I run the example the marker stays in die same place... It does not move to the Atlantic ocean. That sounds, by the way, close to the centre of the earth.

Comment: Works for me in FF11 on Linux and IE8 on Windows (in Southern CA).  Maybe it is a data center dependent problem.

Comment: Update. Saw it happen once after waiting some time on the page (not sure if that is relevant).  Happened again after waiting, went to here: https://maps.google.com/maps?q=https:%2F%2Fsites.google.com%2Fsite%2Fmbkmltest%2Fmy-kml-test%2FTest2.kml&hl=en&ll=0.000831,-0.000772&spn=0.001931,0.002401&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=49.71116,78.662109&t=h&z=19&iwloc=lyrftr:kml:cXOw0bjKUSgN5kcEMpKSOq7cbtgVXF2w350PDRgI,g831b11a5e63031e5,, (as you say ~0,0)

Answer (score 0):

@Mike, you are using what appears to be an older namespace:

```
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
```

Perhaps you'll have better luck by instead using the definitive namespace for KML 2.2:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
```

I also strongly encourage you to make use of this reputable [KML Validator](http://www.kmlvalidator.com).